# How to define rules in the Makefile to compile only that *.cpp files which was modified (and their dependencies), not all *.cpp files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Lets say I have files:

Libs:

- one.cpp, one.h
- two.cpp, two.h
- three.cpp, three.h

Program:

- program.cpp

Is there way, to create Makefile which will compile only that *.cpp which were modified from last compilation?

Currently I have something like that:

```
SRCS = one.cpp two.cpp three.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(OBJS) program

.cpp.o:
    g++ -Wall -c $<

program:
    g++ -Wall $(OBJS) program.cpp -o program

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) program
```

I works fine, but when I compile my program and then change two.cpp or two.h I need to run "make clean" first, because when I secondly run "make" I get:

```
Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

I would like to change my Makefile in that way, it would recognize my changes and recompile that file and its dependencies (if one.cpp uses code from two.cpp which was modified, both files should be recompiled).

So if I modify two.cpp, make should do:

```
g++ -Wall -c two.cpp
g++ -Wall $(OBJS) program.cpp -o program
```

But if one.cpp uses code from two.cpp which was modified, make shold do:

```
g++ -Wall -c one.cpp
g++ -Wall -c two.cpp
g++ -Wall $(OBJS) program.cpp -o program
```

Comment: (I think you mean `one.cpp`, not `first.cpp`.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First we make the object files **prerequisites** of the executable. Once this is done, Make will rebuild `program` whenever one of the SRCS changes, so we don't need `OBJS` as an explicit target:

```
all: program

program: $(OBJS)
  g++ -Wall $(OBJS) program.cpp -o program
```

Then we make the header files prerequisites of the objects, so that if we change three.h, Make will rebuild three.o:

```
$(OBJS): %.o : %.h
```

And finally since one.cpp uses code from two.cpp by means of two.h (I hope), we make two.h a prerequisite of one.o:

```
one.o: two.h
```

And to make things cleaner and easier to maintain we use automatic variables:

```
program: $(OBJS)
  g++ -Wall $^ program.cpp -o $@
```

**Put it all together and we get:**

```
SRCS = one.cpp two.cpp three.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: program

$(OBJS): %.o : %.h

one.o: two.h

.cpp.o:
  g++ -Wall -c $<

program: $(OBJS)
  g++ -Wall $^ program.cpp -o $@

clean:
  rm -f $(OBJS) program
```

There are a few more things we could do (like adding program.o to `OBJS`), but this is enough for today.

Answer (score 1):

Add the files a command depends upon to run to the right of the target name.

Example:

```
default: hello.c
   gcc -o hello.bin hello.c

install: hello.bin
   cp hello.bin ../
```

Comment: Isn't that what `$(OBJS)` is for?

Comment: You tell me, it's your code. I've never used variables in the dependency fields, but there's nothing logically that prevents that from working.

Comment: Variables can be prerequisites, but there are other things that should be prereqs in the OP's makefile besides `$(OBJS)`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is tell `make` that the .o file depends on the .cpp file:

```
%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: That won't solve the problems of dependencies on header files or object files.

Comment: ^^^ this doesn't work for me. Your solution has no rules for %.h targets. Not sure why this was accepted.