# Makefile: multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, g++

In a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602100/) I asked previously, I tried to separate `bin` and `obj` folders from my cpp. My dependency file (`main.d`) will be stored in `obj` directory. However, my attempt faced with problem. Linker believes that somethings are not linked directly:

> /tmp/cc7WetlH.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
>
> /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

```
SOURCES := main.cpp
BINDIR:= ./bin
OBJDIR:= ./bin/obj
OBJECTS := $(OBJDIR)/$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEPFILES:= $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wfatal-errors -std=c++11 -MD -MP
LIBS:= -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system 


all: run

# Link the executable
run: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $(BINDIR)/$@ $(LIBS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF $(OBJDIR)/$*.d -o $@  $<

-include $(DEPFILES)
```

To solve it, I added the linked libraries to compiler (to me it does not make sense):

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF $(OBJDIR)/$*.d -o $@  $< $(LIBS)
```

And the object was created successfully however linker believes that somethings are defined multiple times:

```
g++  bin/obj/main.o -o ./bin/run -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system 
bin/obj/main.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: first defined here
bin/obj/main.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 7
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 8
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 9
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_ranges): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 4
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_ranges): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 4
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_ranges): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 5
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_ranges): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
bin/obj/main.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
bin/obj/main.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
bin/obj/main.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
bin/obj/main.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 4
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_line): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S:64: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
bin/obj/main.o:(.data+0x28): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in bin/obj/main.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Just for the record this line `OBJECTS := $(OBJDIR)/$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)` will not work correctly if you have more than one entry in `$(SOURCES)`. You want `$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))` there.

Comment: Also `-o $(BINDIR)/$@` is a bad idea in a makefile. A recipe should always generate *exactly* `$@` or make won't do things the way you expect. See [Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) for more information.

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks so much. Would you mind suggesting me an alternative way to generate the executable file in `BINDIR`?

Comment: `all: $(BINDIR)/run` and `$(BINDIR)/run: $(OBJECTS)` then just `-o $@`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding linker arguments to compilation lines doesn't make any sense your intuition there was correct.

The problem with your `%.o` rule is that you forget to include the `-c` flag to tell the compiler to stop before linking.

Add that, remove the linker arguments and see if your problem still exists.